# Sql Server replication setup in a high availability clustering system running on a workgroup

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, merge-replication, workgroup, availability-group

We are trying to set up replication for a database in a high availability cluster environment, where an outage of the primary database server will automatically fail over to the secondary server.

Furthermore, we are using a workgroup-based environment rather than domain-based, because in this case a domain controller would be superfluous.

Configuration:
OS: WinServer 2019
SqlServer: 2017
Replication: merge, push-based

We have not be able to get a publisher set up with the name used for the cluster (i.e., the name that resolves to the cluster IP address).  The setup only allows the name of the database server, which resolves to the IP of the primary database server.

Is it possible to set up Sql Server replication in an availability group environment that is workgroup-based?

Comment: Yes you can setup replication solution in workgroup but you will be use same account for do this solution. You will be create a same account with same user name and password on all servers and run sql server agent with this account for all server

Comment: Becouse the replication have many agent ( not sql agent ) for impelement riplication and all of replication agent runed by sql server job by sql server agent permission

Comment: If it will work, how can replication be set up?

Comment: When all of your sql server agent run with that user permission you will be able start config replication as domain server but with same account user